# implement foreign Key in JPA side( in database this relation is nt implemented)

Tags: jpa

how to implement Foreign key relation in JPA side ( There is no foreign key for this relation in db, Db owned by another application , i cant able to change db structure( SW vendor not allowing me to do it)

Answer (score 0):

Is there just no foreign key constraint, or nothing referencing the id at all?

If there is just no constraint, then it does not matter, JPA does not care if there is a constraint or not, just use the column that references the id.

If there is nothing referencing the id, then you cannot have a relationship with nothing store it.  If you cannot alter the table, then perhaps you can add a new table that defines the join between the two tables (similar to a many to many, but JPA also allows a join table to be used for a one to one).